# What is human-level performance for semantic segmentation?

Tags: image-segmentation, performance

I see so many papers claim to have an algorithm that beats 'human-level performance' for semantic segmentation tasks, but I can't find any papers reporting on what the human-level performance actually is. An analysis of the similarity between segmentations drawn by multiple different human experts would be good. Could someone point me towards a paper that reports on something like that?